# What is the Difference between Data mart and DSS(Decision Suport System)?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, olap-cube

I trying to know the difference between Data Mart and DSS

When I check the info in Internet about DSS vs DWH. I found that .

"Data warehouse is often the componet taht stores data for a DSS".
 The problem is that as long as i know DWH is too the componet that stores   data for a Data Mart.
so
What is the difference between a DSS and a Data Mart?

Thanks in advance , Enrique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More appropriate question would be: What is similar with Data Mart and DSS?

Data mart is subject oriented set of related tables where you have one fact table (transactions) and multiple dimension tables (categories). Example: Data mart of sales. Fact table (salesID,agentID,categoryID,dateID,amount,quantity). Dimension Agent (AgentID, AgentName, AgentType, etc)

Data Warehouse (it's database) is centralised repository of aggregated data from one or multiple source aimed to serve for reporting purpose. It's usually denormalized. It could be based on data marts or one logical data model in 3rn normalisation form.

DSS is information system, it's not database neither entity. It lies on data, but it also have it own's model and user interface. Model is critical for decision recommendation engine.

What may led you to misunderstands is because some of DSS lies on DWHs, specifically on Kimball (Data Marts) types of DWHs.